# Fill a multi-table dataset using only a primary key

Tags: c#, dataset

I would like to fill a multi-table DataSet using only a primary key from one table and select everything linked to this table.

Here's a example (Northwind 2007)
http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/4268/northwind2007.png

As you can see, [Orders] is linked to one [Employees] and to many [Order Details] and [Order Details] is linked to one [Product]

What I want is fill my DataSet (Order, Employees, Order Details, Product, etc) using only one Order ID.

```
select * from Orders where [Order ID] = parameter_id
select * from [Employees] where ID = Orders.Employee ID
select * from [Order Details] where Order ID = Orders.Order ID
select * from [Products] where Order Details.Product ID = Products.ID
```

For the moment, that's what I want. If possible, with all the foreign key to ensure parent / children relation.

Comment: Do you mean constraints within dataset?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : Is there a automatically way to do this or I have to run each query separately to fill my DataSet?

Comment: Is there an automatic way to do WHAT exactly? You list 4 queries but don't describe your desired (single) result.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : To fill my DataSet using only the primary key from Orders table. The query are just an example of data my dataset should contain.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens : I want to instanciate a new OrderDataSet, pass it a Order ID, and retrieve employees data (linked by employee id in orders), orders id datas (linked by order id in order details), products datas (linked by product id in orders details) whenever how much data (order details) it may contain.